# Command to make new command

Tags: macros

I have several books with toggles/ifs for each of them (I have toggles and ifs because I had several problems with some other packages..)
I defined the toggles in my style-File like this:

```
 \newtoggle{printer}
 \togglefalse{printer}
 \newif\ifprinter
 \printerfalse
 \newcommand{\printer}{\printertrue\toggletrue{printer}}
```

and defining the type in the Book with the command `\printer`

Since I have like 70 different products I would like to declare a new product in my style file with `\newproduct{printer}` and Latex sets up the lines above. How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just give the printer name as a parameter:

```
\newcommand{\defineprinter}[1]{%
  \newtoggle{#1}%
  \togglefalse{#1}%
  \newbool{#1}%
  \boolfalse{#1}%
  \expandafter\newcommand\csname #1\endcsname{%
    \booltrue{#1}\toggletrue{#1}%
  }%
}
```

Now `\defineprinter{printer}` will do the same as your sample code.

It's a bit complicated because you want to build commands based on the argument, so `\csname` is needed for defining `\printer` (or whatever is passed as argument).

Using `\newbool` ensures the boolean you're going to define is not already defined. After `\newbool{printer}` you have `\ifprinter`, `\printertrue` and `\printerfalse`, because `\newbool` does a `\newif` internally.